# mod_rewrite Forward any incoming Domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to forward any incoming Domain with www and without www to a specific Domain?

I tried something like this but it will not work probably

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you'd be better off just saying `any host which is NOT www.domain.com` should be forwarded. if someone points www.example.com at your server, your rewrite would NOT catch that, because it does start with www.

Comment: Means that I have to rewrite for each Domain the Rule?

Comment: you want this to be a generic rule for all the domains you're hosting? I'm reading it as "redirect all incoming domains to www.domain.com, if they aren't www.domain.com". e.g. many->one.

Comment: Yes I need for the Domains that I am hosting. domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com etc.. should point to domain.com

Comment: then that's all you need. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$`. anything that is NOT exactly www.domain.com should be redirected to it. that'll include `domain.com`, `foo.domain.com`, `ww.domain.com`, `yahoo.com`, etc...

Comment: Thanks Mark! You helped me